# How can I separate parts of a list in the navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Here is my simple sign up page I tried to make. I need help figuring out how to put home, about, help on the left side of the navbar and sign in on the far right side of the bar. I want them on the same navbar but I couldn't find anything on how to separating them or put them on separate sides of the page.

I'm pretty new to html and css so any other tips that can help improve the quality of my first web page would help alright peaces SO peeps.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Sample Sign up App</title>
    <script></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sign up form css.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="nav navbar-left">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li role ="presentation"><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>




<div class ="container">
<div class = "jumbotron">
<h2 id="jumbo-welcome"> Sign up to Sample App today!</h2>
<br>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputFile" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id = "submit-button">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS for the page

```
nav {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1980px;
    height:45px;
    .border;
    .shadow;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 32px;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

 .nav2 li{
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 32px;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
 }

.jumbotron{
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    width:40%;
    height:66%;
    top: 20%;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.form-group{
    display:block;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right:15%;
}
.jumbotron #submit-button{
    display:block;
    margin-left:40%;
    margin-right:35%;
}
#jumbo-welcome{
    text-align:center;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
    background:#F2F2F2;
    background-image: url("http://tech-rx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/background.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this css to your  css code

```
.nav.nav-pills li:last-child{float:right}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/wzeLgnfm/3/)

Comment: @user3043051 u got the result

Answer (score 0):

So I found a cheap way to make the same effect.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="home page.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-left">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navlist">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li id="sign-in-link"><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

assign an id to the sign in link and in css make it go right.

```
#sign-in-link{
    position: absolute;
    left: 95%;
    margin:auto;
}
```